# Windows 10/Chrome: how to disable thumbnails for a specific folder or reset download locations

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, privacy, thumbnails

My issue lies in downloading files in a public setting, as once in a while, the "Save As" menu, ends up in a folder with rather "sensitive" material in it.

So basically I would like to either be able to prevent display of thumbnails in that/those particular folder/s.

Or simply be able to reset all "Save As" download locations, so that whenever I am about to save something, I don't end up playing something akin to a russian roulette...

According to this thread:

https://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/246700-how-can-i-disable-folder-content-preview-but-not-pictures-thumbnails.html

It is only possible to disable thumbnails globally... so unless there is some sort of a third-party program out there, I guess the only choice would be to somehow be able to reset those "Save As" download locations

I am using Chrome by the way